# Random numbers from -10 to 10, A program that will change the max negative of a range in a column and be moved to the first position

Tags: python

Using random numbers from a range of -10 to 10, I want to write a program that will change the places of two columns. A column that contains the maximum negative element, and a column that contains the minimum positive element of the matrix.Lets say the numbers are randomly generated so there can be no 10 or -10 for example lets say for the rows of maximum negative value lets say we have a range of -8 -2 3 5 so the maximum negative value here is -2 so the rows will change to -2 -8 3 5 and for the minimum postive value lets say a range of -4 -2 3 6 8 the number here is 3 so the range will change to 3 -4 -2 6 8 Here is the code that I am working on and this is how far I was able to go but I dont understand how I can introduce the max negative and min positive number. this is the idea that I have in head [image] [image] this is what i get but not sure how to use the maxi and mini in this not sure if i started the equation at the start correctly or not this is what i get with the code at the moment [image]

```
        import random

print("Enter number of cols:")
n = int(input())
print("Enter number of rows:")
m = int(input())

rows, cols = (m, n)
nums=[]
for i in range(rows):
    col = []
    for j in range(cols):
        col.append(random.randint(-10, 10))
    nums.append(col)

for row in nums:
    print(row)

updatedNums = []
for i in range(rows):
    col = []
    for j in range(cols):
        col.append(0)
    updatedNums.append(col)

max_negative = max(nums for nums in nums if nums < 0)

min_positive = min(nums for nums in nums if nums > 0)

for i in range(rows):
  for f in range(cols):
    if nums[i][f] == max_negative:
      updatedNums[i][j] = nums[i][j]
```

Comment: Your examples are about one-dimensional lists, but then your code creates a list of lists. I miss how that relates. Secondly, I don't see any attempt at finding a value in a list... Please add your attempt and where it goes wrong.

Comment: @trincot import random

print("Enter number of cols:")
n = int(input())
print("Enter number of rows:")
m = int(input())

rows, cols = (m, n)
nums=[]
for i in range(rows):
    col = []
    for j in range(cols):
        col.append(random.randint(-10, 10))
    nums.append(col)

for row in nums:
    print(row)

updatedNums = []
try:
    max_negative = max(nums for nums in nums if nums < 0)
except ValueError:
    max_negative = 0
try:
    min_positive = min(nums for nums in nums if nums > 0)
except ValueError:
    min_positive = 0

Comment: @trincot Im trying to find out how to find the maxi and mini from the range without breaking the range so i can add it later on in the new range, im new to programing maybe im trying it wrongly cuz im new to programing

Comment: I can only repeat that your examples are about one-dimensional lists, yet your code works with 2-dimensional lists. Please edit your question and add an example of a 2-dimensional list, and how it should be modified by identifying min/max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do. print statements added to show what the code is doing at each step

```
from random import randint

ncols = int(input('Number of columns: '))
nrows = int(input('Number of rows: '))

data = [[randint(-10, 10) for _ in range(ncols)] for _ in range(nrows)]

for r in data:
    print('Original: ', r)
    maxneg = max(n for n in r if n < 0)
    r.insert(0, r.pop(r.index(maxneg)))
    print('Max -ve moved: ', r)
    minpos = min(n for n in r if n > 0)
    r.insert(0, r.pop(r.index(minpos)))
    print('Min +ve moved: ', r)
```

**Example:**

```
Number of columns: 8
Number of rows: 1
Original:  [-3, -9, -9, -8, 2, -3, -2, -7]
Max -ve moved:  [-2, -3, -9, -9, -8, 2, -3, -7]
Min +ve moved:  [2, -2, -3, -9, -9, -8, -3, -7]
```